# How to create a dictionary from a CSV with two columns as the key in Python

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dictionary

I am trying to create a dictionary from a CSV with 3 columns where the first two columns become the key and the third column becomes the value:

In this example, example.csv contains:

```
Column-1    Column-2   Column-3
1           A          foo
2           B          bar
```

The expected output should be:

```
dictionary = {1, A: foo, 2, B: bar}
```

I am currently attempting to import from a pandas dataframe and convert to a dictionary.  I am using the following unsuccessfully:

```
df = pd.read_csv("example.csv")
dictionary = df.set_index(['Column-1', 'Column-2']).to_dict()
```

Is there a way to do this using pandas to create the dictionary or is there a more elegant way to convert the csv to a dictionary?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IIUC you are close - need select column by `['Column-3']`:

```
d = df.set_index(['Column-1', 'Column-2'])['Column-3'].to_dict()
print (d)
{(2, 'B'): 'bar', (1, 'A'): 'foo'}
```

Answer (score 2):

### Option 1

```
dict(zip(zip(df['Column-1'], df['Column-2']), df['Column-3']))

{(1, 'A'): 'foo', (2, 'B'): 'bar'}
```

---

### Option 2

```
{(a, b): c for a, b, c in df.values}

{(1, 'A'): 'foo', (2, 'B'): 'bar'}
```